# Excel - Select Column by number and sheetname

Tags: vba, excel

I have 4 columns on Sheet1 and 4 on Sheet2
I have named the columnson sheet 1 as:

```
MvarNo = 1
Mdesc = 2
Mfile = 3
Mfield = 4
```

where 1 = a etc....

How do I name these columns with the sheet name and column number?

Thanks

UPDATE

```
Sub Compare()

MvarNo = 1 'Sheet1
Mdesc = 2 'Sheet1
Mfile = 3 'Sheet1
Mfield = 4 'Sheet1

XvarNo = 6 'Sheet1
Xdesc = 7 'Sheet1
Xfile = 8 'Sheet1
Xfield = 9 'Sheet1

CvarNo = 1 'Sheet2
Cdesc = 2 'Sheet2
Cfile = 3 'Sheet2
Cfield = 4 'Sheet2

'Count rows on Master Sheet (Sheet1)
MvarNoLastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
MdesclastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
 MfilelastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
MfieldlastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

'Count rows on Compare Sheet (Sheet2)
CvarNoLastRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
CdesclastRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
CfilelastRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
CfieldlastRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To MvarNoLastRow
For j = 2 To CvarNoLastRow

  If Cells(i, MvarNo) = Cells(j, CvarNo) Then
  Cells(i, XvarNo).Value = "Yes"
'        If Cells(i, MvarNo) = Cells(j, CvarNo) And Cells(i, Mdesc) = Cells(j, Cdesc) And Cells(i, Mfile) = Cells(j, Cfile) And Cells(i, Mfield) = Cells(j,     Cfield) Then
'        Cells(i, XvarNo).Value = "Yes"
'        ElseIf Cells(i, MvarNo) <> Cells(j, CvarNo) And Cells(i, Mdesc) <>     Cells(j, Cdesc) And Cells(i, Mfile) <> Cells(j, Cfile) And Cells(i, Mfield) <>     Cells(j, Cfield) Then
      j = j + 1
    ElseIf j = CvarNoLastRow Then
    Cells(i, XvarNo).Value = "No"


  End If

  Next j


Next i

End Sub
```

the reason for this macro is to compare information between sheet 1 and sheet2.
I 'think' from my code it is actually just comparing the data on sheet 1 with sheet1.

Comment: Think you need to be more specific about your goal, you could be trying to create a reference to a cell address, or create a range or all sorts of other things... Or it could be as simple as `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(somerow, MvarNo)` (assuming you had defined the columns in code somewhere, which is hard to tell from your post)

Comment: `Cells(i, MvarNo)` is interpreted as `ActiveSheet.Cells(i, MvarNo)`. You need to add the worksheet in front: `Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, MvarNo)`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

Here my sheet is called "Ad revenues"

```
Sub test()
    Dim lC As Long
    Dim strColNames(1 To 4) As String
    For lC = 1 To 4
        strColNames(lC) = Sheet1.Name & vbTab & Str(Cells(1, lC).Column)
    Next lC End Sub
End Sub()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the sheet name, all of the following will work:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename"),LEFT(CELL("filename"),FIND("]",CELL("filename"))),"")

=RIGHT(CELL("filename"),LEN(CELL("filename"))-FIND("]",CELL("filename")))    

=MID(CELL("filename"),FIND("]",CELL("filename"))+1,31)
```

The latter works because excel limits you to 31 characters when naming a sheet

To get the name of a column, you can use something like below:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(ADDRESS(1,CELL("col")),2,2),"$","")

=MID(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(R31)),"$1",""),2,2)
```